# How to Know that on which channel the coupon has been used in Magento?

Tags: coupon

How we can check that on which channel the coupon has been used. Web or mobile in Magento?

Comment: Are you new to StackExchange? What are the details that you have provided here? On what basis you are expecting the solution from us.  Which version of magento are you using? What the ways that you have tried so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to see this by default. You would need to save this somewhere related to the coupon.
You could also use google analytics and trigger a Event, there you can properly filter for different devices used.